How do I use Zenject's Method Injection when there are parameters in the constructor?
public interface IVector3ValueList
{
    public List<Vector3> GetVector3List();
}

public class Vector3ListGetter : IVector3ValueList
{
    private List<float> xList, yList, zList;
    public Vector3ListGetter(List<float> xList, List<float> yList, List<float> zList)
    {
        this.xList = xList;
        this.yList = yList;
        this.zList = zList;
    }
    public List<Vector3> GetVector3List()
    {
        float minX = xList.Min();
        float minY = yList.Min();
        float minZ = zList.Min();

        // return ...
    }
}

public class StartingPos : MonoBehaviour
{
    public JsonConverter jsonConverter;
    private IVector3ValueList _iVector3ValueList;
    private List<Vector3> vertex;

    private void Start()
    {
        _iVector3ValueList = new Vector3ListGetter(jsonConverter.XList, 
        jsonConverter.YList, jsonConverter.ZList);   // What do I want to delete
        vertex = _iVector3ValueList.GetVector3List();
    }
}

This is an example of the code I want to use. I purposely used the interface for an example. And I wrote the following for Method Injection.
public class StartingPos : MonoBehaviour
{
    public JsonConverter jsonConverter;
    private IVector3ValueList _iVector3ValueList;
    private List<Vector3> vertex;

    [Inject]
    public void Init(IVector3ValueList iVector3ValueList)
    {
        _iVector3ValueList = iVector3ValueList;
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        _iVector3ValueList = new Vector3ListGetter(jsonConverter.XList, 
        jsonConverter.YList, jsonConverter.ZList);   // What do I want to delete
        vertex = _iVector3ValueList.GetVector3List();
    }
}

But it doesn't work properly because it didn't get the constructor parameters.
new Vector3ListGetter(jsonConverter.XList, jsonConverter.YList, jsonConverter.ZList)
How should I inject this object? In similar situations, it worked properly when there were no parameters in the constructor.
public class InterfaceInstaller : MonoInstaller
{
    public override void InstallBindings()
    {
        Container.Bind<IPipeVector3ValueList>().To<CornerPipesVector3ListGetter>().AsSingle();
    }
}

